# Make radio buttons disappear in close dialog if I have an active close vote on a question

Tags: feature-request, voting, vote-to-close, user-interface, close-dialog

> ***Note:*** This [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) has been posted as [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/346663/468333) to the [announcement of the close UI changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346638/468333).

Earlier when I used to cast a close vote, the dialog would look like this:

[image: old screenshot of close dialog without radio buttons after vote was cast]

That is, the radio buttons used to disappear. But now since the redesign of the close vote dialog, the radio buttons don't disappear:

[image: close dialog screenshot with radio buttons after vote was cast]

Or at least make test distinguishable like that of flags:

[image: “this is the flag you currently have raised” in red in flag dialog]

Comment: Please move or copy this to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346638/256282

Comment: @curiousdannii Done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question Close Updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346638/question-close-updates) - now that there's an official announcement, reports and feature-request​s belong there. Better not to have info scattered all over the place