# Why is the close reason returned by the API different?

Tags: support, close-reasons, api

Up to few moments ago my script was working correctly fetching question information from the API. Right now my script fails because the duplicate close reason is different.

Previously it was:

> Duplicate of…

Now it is:

> Duplicate

Also Off-topic is now:

> Not suitable for this site

Comment: Probably a bug fix. It used to be "duplicate" (with a lowercase D) until the post notices were revamped. The "of..." was never supposed to be there, since the word "of" was already in the notice otherwise.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog I can accept that as an improvement, but I do not see this being announced anywhere and they know that a lot of our scripts depend on these values unchanged. If they gave a week notice about this bug fix I would have enough time to read it and adjust my script.

Comment: I'd honestly change your script to check for just the word "duplicate" (in any casing) rather than checking for the exact text. It's worth noting that older questions closed prior to February 2013 have the text "exact duplicate" in the notice instead, so your script won't detect those properly.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog I check for both and make a distinction between them. Applying regex to handle this seems like a hack, but I think I will have to cave in and do something like this.

Comment: The problem is that SE treats these properties in the SE API as what they want presented to the user, rather than as something which is to be consumed by a program. They don't have fields which are explicitly intended to be interpreted in a programmatic manner and ones which are intended to be user-readable. Thus, the values in these fields change whenever SE chooses to adjust their UI. The API *really* should return both a invariable code which indicates the type of closure, and, if SE wants, human-readable text which they prefer to be used to present the type of closure to the user.

Comment: Alternately, and potentially better, the API could return only an invariant code to represent the type of closure, and there could be another API call which provides SE's preferred mapping of those codes to human-readable text.

Comment: @Makyen There is a close reason ID in the database, which does not change; I don't know if that can be accessed in the database or not. In this case, it's 1 (for old, pre-Feb. 2013 closures) and 101 (for later closures).

Comment: There was a [comment in The Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8339378#8339378), but you should improve your question by mentioning that the API should have a *Beta Version* where the updates can be viewed and discussed, APPs and Scripts can be updated, and ***then*** the implementation can be pushed. That seems hopeful, but it's the better way; if *everything* is to work.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a result of the close interface being revamped.

The "off topic" reason was indeed renamed "not suitable for this site" or "a community specific issue" - the term "off-topic" seems to be in the middle of getting phased out. The "duplicate" change most likely happened at the same time while people were already poking around in there.

You can read more about the changes and give feedback at [Question Close Updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346638/294691).

Comment: "*a community specific issue*"? Is this one of the reason? Can you show an example, please?

Comment: @Dharman - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytRg1.jpg

Comment: You mean to say in the close dialog it is called "a community specific issue', but in the API it is "not suitable for this site"?

Comment: If you continue along the path after selecting "a community specific reason", you are presented with something saying "Why is this question not suitable for this site?" So yeah, the UI has been revamped and uses those two phrases instead of off-topic.