# SEDE appears to be partially-refreshed

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

I went to check some of my queries against UNIX & Linux this morning and noticed that the results all had dates older than a week. Going to [rene's](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/11779) ["did the SEDE refresh work?"](https://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/848198/did-the-sede-refresh-work) query, I see that U&L is among the sites whose most recent posts/comments are 2020-04-19 instead of 2020-04-26, as expected. *Partial* results of incompletely-refreshed sites are:

```
...
StackExchange.Meta                    2020-04-19 05:15:09 comments 
StackExchange.Ubuntu                  2020-04-19 05:08:40 comments 
StackExchange.Stats                   2020-04-19 05:06:54 comments 
StackExchange.Ubuntu                  2020-04-19 05:02:17 posts    
StackExchange.Programmers             2020-04-19 04:51:22 comments 
StackExchange.Programmers             2020-04-19 04:48:14 posts    
StackExchange.Gaming                  2020-04-19 04:46:57 posts    
StackExchange.Stats                   2020-04-19 04:40:08 posts    
StackExchange.Meta                    2020-04-19 04:36:48 posts    
StackExchange.English                 2020-04-19 04:34:46 comments 
StackExchange.Math                    2020-04-19 04:32:38 comments 
StackExchange.Tex                     2020-04-19 04:25:59 posts    
StackExchange.Math                    2020-04-19 04:22:14 posts    
StackExchange.Tex                     2020-04-19 04:19:32 comments 
StackExchange.Unix                    2020-04-19 04:17:12 comments 
StackExchange.English                 2020-04-19 04:15:42 posts    
StackExchange.Unix                    2020-04-19 04:15:31 posts    
StackExchange.Gis                     2020-04-19 04:14:44 posts    
StackExchange.Electronics             2020-04-19 04:11:13 comments 
...
```

Sorting by date doesn't make it obvious to me *where* the refresh died/stopped, but hopefully this post alerts the correct people.

Comment: It seems something failed: https://twitter.com/tarynpivots/status/1254423433686867969?s=20, apparently because of the new close reasons: https://twitter.com/tarynpivots/status/1254435296906641409?s=20

Comment: Thanks, @Tinkeringbell! To taryn's "do I fix it today?" -- please do not work if you're not scheduled to, Taryn! SEDE can wait :)

Comment: Yes I’m aware of this. I know what caused it but we need to discuss possible fixes for it. I unbroke it enough to allow for querying across all sites. We’ll look more tomorrow and I’ll kick the job once things have been fixed.

Comment: @Taryn I recall a discussion, possibly with Catija, appropriately a month ago, where there was some delay/breakage in SEDE's updating - might be hidden in comments on MSE, probably not in The Tavern (but, maybe).

Comment: I have created this [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1239509/status-of-the-sede-refresh-on-sunday-0300-utc?cachebreaker=0) that gives insight in what the current state is for all SEDE databases and if there is a restore going on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should be resolved soon. I have kicked off the refresh process and it's made it past the previous error that resulted in the failure. The full refresh takes about 6-7 hours, so it will be a little while for all the databases to refresh.

---

Here is a quick summary of the issue.

We recently made a change to the [Close UI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346638/question-close-updates), and in making those changes, we updated the interface for [moderators to manage specific close reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396754/question-close-updates-phase-1).

**How that impacted SEDE?**

We populate SEDE by using views to select from each table we're going to export. One of the tables we export is the `CloseAsOffTopicReasons`. The change to the Close UI allowed a column to hold values that were `null`, but the import was looking for non-nullable columns - these don't play nicely with each other and the import went boom.

We updated the view for the `CloseAsOffTopicReasons` to no longer contain the nullable column, and actually added some new columns to it. The new list of columns for the table in SEDE is:

- Id
- IsUniversal
- InputTitle
- MarkdownInputGuidance
- MarkdownPostOwnerGuidance
- MarkdownPublicGuidance *(initially called MarkdownPrivilegedUserGuidance)*
- MarkdownConcensusDescription (sic)
- CreationDate
- CreationModeratorId
- ApprovalDate
- ApprovalModeratorId
- DeactivationDate
- DeactivationModeratorId

Comment: Nice! So the actual trick for getting more data in SEDE (e.g. a 'user is a moderator' indicator) is 1) ask for a related feature request 2) make sure it gets implemented in a way that breaks SEDE 3) ... 4) profit?

Comment: Don't get any ideas. :P

Comment: Thank you, Taryn! I suppose "we" should update the list in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/307535 too?

Comment: I've updated the Database schema documentation in the link above. Taryn, please accept my thanks (and pass them on to Nick and anyone else involved) for handling this today and not "off-hours". I support a good work-life balance! :)