# No new data on https://data.stackexchange.com/

Tags: bug, data-explorer

I noticed that the newest data for some tags from Stack Overflow is a week old. An example is here:  *https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1232357/1515799/custom-questions-between-time-and-response-times*

Why is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SEDE appears to be partially-refreshed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347039/sede-appears-to-be-partially-refreshed)

Comment: There was an issue with the weekly refresh. We're working on it