# SEDE refresh seems to be stuck (again)

Tags: bug, data-explorer

The weekly SEDE refresh doesn't seem to have completed successfully, just like [two weeks ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347039/295232); the Stack Overflow and Super User database are still a week old. If you look at the [database timestamps](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1236884), everything seems to have run smoothly up to 15:00 UTC when it was Super User's turn to be restored. The new site [Drones.SE](https://drones.stackexchange.com/) does also appear not to have been added. Last time it was the close reasons; perhaps the [bookmarks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347558/295232) can be blamed this time?

Comment: I asked but [it was said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347558/favorites-are-now-known-as-bookmarks#comment1163132_347558) that no vote types were hurt in the renaming of that feature ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SEDE now seems to be updated.

Running [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1236884) results in:

```
...
StackExchange.Drones.Meta   2020-05-10 12:29:43
StackExchange.Drones    2020-05-10 12:29:45
StackExchange.Or.Meta   2020-05-10 12:29:47
StackExchange.Or    2020-05-10 12:29:50
StackExchange.Tezos.Meta    2020-05-10 12:29:52
StackExchange.Tezos 2020-05-10 12:29:55
StackExchange.Eosio.Meta    2020-05-10 12:29:57
StackExchange.Eosio 2020-05-10 12:30:01
StackExchange.Quantumcomputing.Meta 2020-05-10 12:30:03
StackExchange.Quantumcomputing  2020-05-10 12:30:09
StackExchange.Conlang.Meta  2020-05-10 12:30:11
StackExchange.Conlang   2020-05-10 12:30:14
StackExchange.Stellar.Meta  2020-05-10 12:30:16
StackExchange.Stellar   2020-05-10 12:30:19
StackExchange.Iota.Meta 2020-05-10 12:30:21
StackExchange.Iota  2020-05-10 12:30:24
StackExchange.Interpersonal.Meta    2020-05-10 12:30:29
StackExchange.Interpersonal 2020-05-10 12:30:41
StackExchange.Cseducators.Meta  2020-05-10 12:30:43
StackExchange.Cseducators   2020-05-10 12:30:47
StackExchange.Bioinformatics.Meta   2020-05-10 12:30:52
StackExchange.Bioinformatics    2020-05-10 12:30:59
StackExchange.Devops.Meta   2020-05-10 12:31:04
StackExchange.Devops    2020-05-10 12:31:09
StackExchange.Ukrainian.Meta    2020-05-10 12:31:11
StackExchange.Ukrainian 2020-05-10 12:31:18
StackExchange.Vegetarian.Meta   2020-05-10 12:31:24
StackExchange.Vegetarian    2020-05-10 12:31:30
StackExchange.Literature.Meta   2020-05-10 12:31:32
StackExchange.Literature    2020-05-10 12:31:41
StackExchange.Iot.Meta  2020-05-10 12:31:43
StackExchange.Iot   2020-05-10 12:31:50
StackExchange.Sitecore.Meta 2020-05-10 12:31:59
StackExchange.Sitecore  2020-05-10 12:32:14
StackExchange.Esperanto.Meta    2020-05-10 12:32:19
StackExchange.Esperanto 2020-05-10 12:32:31
StackExchange.Ai.Meta   2020-05-10 12:32:43
StackExchange.Ai    2020-05-10 12:32:59
StackExchange.Monero.Meta   2020-05-10 12:33:04
StackExchange.Monero    2020-05-10 12:33:12
StackExchange.Korean.Meta   2020-05-10 12:33:17
StackExchange.Korean    2020-05-10 12:33:24
StackExchange.Crafts.Meta   2020-05-10 12:33:28
StackExchange.Crafts    2020-05-10 12:33:31
StackExchange.Retrocomputing.Meta   2020-05-10 12:33:34
StackExchange.Retrocomputing    2020-05-10 12:33:42
StackExchange.Languagelearning.Meta 2020-05-10 12:33:51
StackExchange.Languagelearning  2020-05-10 12:34:04
StackExchange.Latin.Meta    2020-05-10 12:34:10
StackExchange.Latin 2020-05-10 12:34:22
StackExchange.Ethereum.Meta 2020-05-10 12:34:27
StackExchange.Ethereum  2020-05-10 12:35:06
StackExchange.3dprinting.Meta   2020-05-10 12:35:12
StackExchange.3dprinting    2020-05-10 12:35:20
StackOverflow.Es.Meta   2020-05-10 12:35:25
StackOverflow.Es    2020-05-10 12:37:39
StackExchange.Hardwarerecs.Meta 2020-05-10 12:37:43
StackExchange.Hardwarerecs  2020-05-10 12:37:55
StackExchange.Computergraphics.Meta 2020-05-10 12:38:04
StackExchange.Computergraphics  2020-05-10 12:38:14
StackExchange.Portuguese.Meta   2020-05-10 12:38:21
StackExchange.Portuguese    2020-05-10 12:38:29
StackExchange.Elementaryos.Meta 2020-05-10 12:38:34
StackExchange.Elementaryos  2020-05-10 12:38:52
StackExchange.Opensource.Meta   2020-05-10 12:38:54
StackExchange.Opensource    2020-05-10 12:39:00
StackExchange.Law.Meta  2020-05-10 12:39:03
StackExchange.Law   2020-05-10 12:39:31
StackExchange.Mythology.Meta    2020-05-10 12:39:33
StackExchange.Mythology 2020-05-10 12:39:42
StackExchange.Rus.Meta  2020-05-10 12:39:47
StackExchange.Rus   2020-05-10 12:40:05
StackExchange.Health.Meta   2020-05-10 12:40:12
StackExchange.Health    2020-05-10 12:40:27
StackExchange.Civicrm.Meta  2020-05-10 12:40:41
StackExchange.Civicrm   2020-05-10 12:40:49
StackOverflow.Ru.Meta   2020-05-10 12:40:58
StackOverflow.Ru    2020-05-10 12:45:41
StackExchange.Woodworking.Meta  2020-05-10 12:45:43
StackExchange.Woodworking   2020-05-10 12:45:52
StackExchange.Musicfans.Meta    2020-05-10 12:45:57
StackExchange.Musicfans 2020-05-10 12:46:01
StackExchange.Vi.Meta   2020-05-10 12:46:06
StackExchange.Vi    2020-05-10 12:46:20
StackExchange.Coffee.Meta   2020-05-10 12:46:26
StackExchange.Coffee    2020-05-10 12:46:32
StackExchange.Engineering.Meta  2020-05-10 12:46:38
StackExchange.Engineering   2020-05-10 12:46:48
StackExchange.Lifehacks.Meta    2020-05-10 12:46:51
StackExchange.Lifehacks 2020-05-10 12:47:00
StackOverflow.Ja.Meta   2020-05-10 12:47:04
StackOverflow.Ja    2020-05-10 12:47:21
StackExchange.Economics.Meta    2020-05-10 12:47:24
StackExchange.Economics 2020-05-10 12:47:40
StackExchange.Hsm.Meta  2020-05-10 12:47:43
StackExchange.Hsm   2020-05-10 12:47:53
StackExchange.Emacs.Meta    2020-05-10 12:47:59
StackExchange.Emacs 2020-05-10 12:48:17
StackExchange.Worldbuilding.Meta    2020-05-10 12:48:28
StackExchange.Worldbuilding 2020-05-10 12:50:12
StackExchange.Moderators.Meta   2020-05-10 12:50:14
StackExchange.Moderators    2020-05-10 12:50:20
StackExchange.Hinduism.Meta 2020-05-10 12:50:27
StackExchange.Hinduism  2020-05-10 12:50:49
StackExchange.Buddhism.Meta 2020-05-10 12:50:55
StackExchange.Buddhism  2020-05-10 12:51:17
StackExchange.Craftcms.Meta 2020-05-10 12:51:19
StackExchange.Craftcms  2020-05-10 12:51:31
StackExchange.Puzzling.Meta 2020-05-10 12:51:39
StackExchange.Puzzling  2020-05-10 12:52:15
StackExchange.Datascience.Meta  2020-05-10 12:52:20
StackExchange.Datascience   2020-05-10 12:52:46
StackExchange.Joomla.Meta   2020-05-10 12:52:51
StackExchange.Joomla    2020-05-10 12:53:07
StackOverflow.Meta  2020-05-10 12:54:36
StackExchange.Earthscience.Meta 2020-05-10 12:54:42
StackExchange.Earthscience  2020-05-10 12:54:55
StackExchange.Matheducators.Meta    2020-05-10 12:55:00
StackExchange.Matheducators 2020-05-10 12:55:10
StackExchange.Expatriates.Meta  2020-05-10 12:55:12
StackExchange.Expatriates   2020-05-10 12:55:24
StackExchange.Arduino.Meta  2020-05-10 12:55:30
StackExchange.Arduino   2020-05-10 12:55:59
StackExchange.Softwarerecs.Meta 2020-05-10 12:56:06
StackExchange.Softwarerecs  2020-05-10 12:56:24
StackExchange.Beer.Meta 2020-05-10 12:56:26
StackExchange.Beer  2020-05-10 12:56:33
StackOverflow.Br.Meta   2020-05-10 12:56:42
StackOverflow.Br    2020-05-10 12:59:30
StackExchange.Ebooks.Meta   2020-05-10 12:59:36
StackExchange.Ebooks    2020-05-10 12:59:43
StackExchange.Aviation.Meta 2020-05-10 12:59:49
StackExchange.Aviation  2020-05-10 13:00:24
StackExchange.Italian.Meta  2020-05-10 13:00:31
StackExchange.Italian   2020-05-10 13:00:36
StackExchange.Ham.Meta  2020-05-10 13:00:38
StackExchange.Ham   2020-05-10 13:00:47
StackExchange.Pets.Meta 2020-05-10 13:00:49
StackExchange.Pets  2020-05-10 13:01:05
StackExchange.Tor.Meta  2020-05-10 13:01:07
StackExchange.Tor   2020-05-10 13:01:18
StackExchange.Astronomy.Meta    2020-05-10 13:01:24
StackExchange.Astronomy 2020-05-10 13:01:42
StackExchange.Sound.Meta    2020-05-10 13:01:44
StackExchange.Sound 2020-05-10 13:01:57
StackExchange.Space.Meta    2020-05-10 13:02:03
StackExchange.Space 2020-05-10 13:02:25
StackExchange.Blender.Meta  2020-05-10 13:02:32
StackExchange.Blender   2020-05-10 13:03:16
StackExchange.Freelancing.Meta  2020-05-10 13:03:18
StackExchange.Freelancing   2020-05-10 13:03:24
StackExchange.Opendata.Meta 2020-05-10 13:03:30
StackExchange.Opendata  2020-05-10 13:03:38
StackExchange.Networkengineering.Meta   2020-05-10 13:03:44
StackExchange.Networkengineering    2020-05-10 13:04:06
StackExchange.Reverseengineering.Meta   2020-05-10 13:04:08
StackExchange.Reverseengineering    2020-05-10 13:04:25
StackExchange.Tridion.Meta  2020-05-10 13:04:31
StackExchange.Tridion   2020-05-10 13:04:44
StackExchange.Sustainability.Meta   2020-05-10 13:04:50
StackExchange.Sustainability    2020-05-10 13:05:01
StackExchange.Ell.Meta  2020-05-10 13:05:17
StackExchange.Ell   2020-05-10 13:06:36
StackExchange.Magento.Meta  2020-05-10 13:06:42
StackExchange.Magento   2020-05-10 13:08:29
StackExchange.Anime.Meta    2020-05-10 13:08:37
StackExchange.Anime 2020-05-10 13:09:00
StackExchange.Politics.Meta 2020-05-10 13:09:08
StackExchange.Politics  2020-05-10 13:09:29
StackExchange.Expressionengine.Meta 2020-05-10 13:09:39
StackExchange.Expressionengine  2020-05-10 13:09:50
StackExchange.Robotics.Meta 2020-05-10 13:09:56
StackExchange.Robotics  2020-05-10 13:10:05
StackExchange.Genealogy.Meta    2020-05-10 13:10:12
StackExchange.Genealogy 2020-05-10 13:10:22
StackExchange.Patents.Meta  2020-05-10 13:10:24
StackExchange.Patents   2020-05-10 13:10:38
StackExchange.Salesforce.Meta   2020-05-10 13:10:47
StackExchange.Salesforce    2020-05-10 13:12:22
StackExchange.Islam.Meta    2020-05-10 13:12:27
StackExchange.Islam 2020-05-10 13:12:46
StackExchange.Russian.Meta  2020-05-10 13:12:48
StackExchange.Russian   2020-05-10 13:12:58
StackExchange.Raspberrypi.Meta  2020-05-10 13:13:04
StackExchange.Raspberrypi   2020-05-10 13:13:46
StackExchange.Chess.Meta    2020-05-10 13:13:52
StackExchange.Chess 2020-05-10 13:14:04
StackExchange.Chemistry.Meta    2020-05-10 13:14:12
StackExchange.Chemistry 2020-05-10 13:15:02
StackExchange.Windowsphone.Meta 2020-05-10 13:15:07
StackExchange.Windowsphone  2020-05-10 13:15:12
StackExchange.Workplace.Meta    2020-05-10 13:15:20
StackExchange.Workplace 2020-05-10 13:16:31
StackExchange.Cs.Meta   2020-05-10 13:16:38
StackExchange.Cs    2020-05-10 13:17:18
StackExchange.Academia.Meta 2020-05-10 13:17:27
StackExchange.Academia  2020-05-10 13:18:07
StackExchange.Sports.Meta   2020-05-10 13:18:10
StackExchange.Sports    2020-05-10 13:18:22
StackExchange.Martialarts.Meta  2020-05-10 13:18:32
StackExchange.Martialarts   2020-05-10 13:18:41
StackExchange.Outdoors.Meta 2020-05-10 13:18:48
StackExchange.Outdoors  2020-05-10 13:19:03
StackExchange.Cogsci.Meta   2020-05-10 13:19:13
StackExchange.Cogsci    2020-05-10 13:19:31
StackExchange.Poker.Meta    2020-05-10 13:19:37
StackExchange.Poker 2020-05-10 13:19:45
StackExchange.Biology.Meta  2020-05-10 13:19:52
StackExchange.Biology   2020-05-10 13:20:25
StackExchange.Chinese.Meta  2020-05-10 13:20:28
StackExchange.Chinese   2020-05-10 13:20:40
StackExchange.Movies.Meta   2020-05-10 13:20:44
StackExchange.Movies    2020-05-10 13:21:18
StackExchange.Scicomp.Meta  2020-05-10 13:21:25
StackExchange.Scicomp   2020-05-10 13:21:38
StackExchange.Spanish.Meta  2020-05-10 13:21:46
StackExchange.Spanish   2020-05-10 13:22:00
StackExchange.Bricks.Meta   2020-05-10 13:22:06
StackExchange.Bricks    2020-05-10 13:22:15
StackExchange.History.Meta  2020-05-10 13:22:23
StackExchange.History   2020-05-10 13:22:51
StackExchange.Hermeneutics.Meta 2020-05-10 13:23:00
StackExchange.Hermeneutics  2020-05-10 13:23:21
StackExchange.Linguistics.Meta  2020-05-10 13:23:24
StackExchange.Linguistics   2020-05-10 13:23:41
StackExchange.Bitcoin.Meta  2020-05-10 13:23:44
StackExchange.Bitcoin   2020-05-10 13:24:09
StackExchange.French.Meta   2020-05-10 13:24:15
StackExchange.French    2020-05-10 13:24:31
StackExchange.Dsp.Meta  2020-05-10 13:24:37
StackExchange.Dsp   2020-05-10 13:25:07
StackExchange.Crypto.Meta   2020-05-10 13:25:10
StackExchange.Crypto    2020-05-10 13:25:39
StackExchange.Gardening.Meta    2020-05-10 13:25:45
StackExchange.Gardening 2020-05-10 13:25:58
StackExchange.Philosophy.Meta   2020-05-10 13:26:01
StackExchange.Philosophy    2020-05-10 13:26:44
StackExchange.Japanese.Meta 2020-05-10 13:26:52
StackExchange.Japanese  2020-05-10 13:27:22
StackExchange.German.Meta   2020-05-10 13:27:29
StackExchange.German    2020-05-10 13:27:47
StackExchange.Sqa.Meta  2020-05-10 13:27:52
StackExchange.Sqa   2020-05-10 13:28:07
StackExchange.Music.Meta    2020-05-10 13:28:14
StackExchange.Music 2020-05-10 13:28:41
StackExchange.Parenting.Meta    2020-05-10 13:28:44
StackExchange.Parenting 2020-05-10 13:29:04
StackExchange.Garage.Meta   2020-05-10 13:29:10
StackExchange.Garage    2020-05-10 13:29:37
StackExchange.Fitness.Meta  2020-05-10 13:29:39
StackExchange.Fitness   2020-05-10 13:29:50
StackExchange.Pm.Meta   2020-05-10 13:29:56
StackExchange.Pm    2020-05-10 13:30:08
StackExchange.Quant.Meta    2020-05-10 13:30:17
StackExchange.Quant 2020-05-10 13:30:39
StackExchange.Codegolf.Meta 2020-05-10 13:30:54
StackExchange.Codegolf  2020-05-10 13:32:48
StackExchange.Codereview.Meta   2020-05-10 13:32:58
StackExchange.Codereview    2020-05-10 13:36:03
StackExchange.Graphicdesign.Meta    2020-05-10 13:36:06
StackExchange.Graphicdesign 2020-05-10 13:36:42
StackExchange.Audio.Meta    2020-05-10 13:36:59
StackExchange.Audio 2020-05-10 13:37:13
StackExchange.Writers.Meta  2020-05-10 13:37:31
StackExchange.Writers   2020-05-10 13:40:54
StackExchange.Homebrew.Meta 2020-05-10 13:41:44
StackExchange.Homebrew  2020-05-10 13:41:52
StackExchange.Boardgames.Meta   2020-05-10 13:41:58
StackExchange.Boardgames    2020-05-10 13:42:15
StackExchange.Money.Meta    2020-05-10 13:42:24
StackExchange.Money 2020-05-10 13:42:59
StackExchange.Mathoverflow.Meta 2020-05-10 13:43:07
StackExchange.Mathoverflow  2020-05-10 13:45:10
StackExchange.Christianity.Meta 2020-05-10 13:45:20
StackExchange.Christianity  2020-05-10 13:45:53
StackExchange.Travel.Meta   2020-05-10 13:46:03
StackExchange.Travel    2020-05-10 13:46:50
StackExchange.Mathematica.Meta  2020-05-10 13:46:57
StackExchange.Mathematica   2020-05-10 13:48:40
StackExchange.Rpg.Meta  2020-05-10 13:48:47
StackExchange.Rpg   2020-05-10 13:50:01
StackExchange.Judaism.Meta  2020-05-10 13:50:13
StackExchange.Judaism   2020-05-10 13:50:52
StackExchange.Skeptics.Meta 2020-05-10 13:50:56
StackExchange.Skeptics  2020-05-10 13:51:27
StackExchange.Scifi.Meta    2020-05-10 13:51:54
StackExchange.Scifi 2020-05-10 13:53:22
StackExchange.Ux.Meta   2020-05-10 13:53:25
StackExchange.Ux    2020-05-10 13:54:10
StackExchange.Diy.Meta  2020-05-10 13:54:16
StackExchange.Diy   2020-05-10 13:55:03
StackExchange.Bicycles.Meta 2020-05-10 13:55:09
StackExchange.Bicycles  2020-05-10 13:55:30
StackExchange.Sharepoint.Meta   2020-05-10 13:55:37
StackExchange.Sharepoint    2020-05-10 13:56:43
StackExchange.Dba.Meta  2020-05-10 13:56:53
StackExchange.Dba   2020-05-10 13:58:29
StackExchange.Drupal.Meta   2020-05-10 13:58:35
StackExchange.Drupal    2020-05-10 13:59:32
StackExchange.Security.Meta 2020-05-10 13:59:35
StackExchange.Security  2020-05-10 14:00:54
StackExchange.Physics.Meta  2020-05-10 14:01:01
StackExchange.Physics   2020-05-10 14:04:04
StackExchange.Android.Meta  2020-05-10 14:04:10
StackExchange.Android   2020-05-10 14:04:55
StackExchange.Wordpress.Meta    2020-05-10 14:05:08
StackExchange.Wordpress 2020-05-10 14:06:52
StackExchange.Electronics.Meta  2020-05-10 14:06:58
StackExchange.Electronics   2020-05-10 14:09:33
StackExchange.Gis.Meta  2020-05-10 14:09:40
StackExchange.Gis   2020-05-10 14:11:24
StackExchange.Apple.Meta    2020-05-10 14:11:32
StackExchange.Apple 2020-05-10 14:13:07
StackExchange.Cooking.Meta  2020-05-10 14:13:11
StackExchange.Cooking   2020-05-10 14:13:38
StackExchange.Unix.Meta 2020-05-10 14:13:45
StackExchange.Unix  2020-05-10 14:16:47
StackExchange.Math.Meta 2020-05-10 14:17:07
StackExchange.Math  2020-05-10 14:31:22
StackExchange.Cstheory.Meta 2020-05-10 14:31:29
StackExchange.Cstheory  2020-05-10 14:31:52
StackExchange.Tex.Meta  2020-05-10 14:32:02
StackExchange.Tex   2020-05-10 14:35:50
StackExchange.English.Meta  2020-05-10 14:36:00
StackExchange.English   2020-05-10 14:38:04
StackExchange.Programmers.Meta  2020-05-10 14:38:24
StackExchange.Programmers   2020-05-10 14:40:41
StackExchange.Gaming.Meta   2020-05-10 14:40:48
StackExchange.Gaming    2020-05-10 14:42:31
StackExchange.Webmasters.Meta   2020-05-10 14:42:40
StackExchange.Webmasters    2020-05-10 14:43:19
StackExchange.GameDev.Meta  2020-05-10 14:43:26
StackExchange.GameDev   2020-05-10 14:44:33
StackExchange.WebApps.Meta  2020-05-10 14:44:40
StackApps   2020-05-10 14:44:49
StackExchange.Ubuntu.Meta   2020-05-10 14:44:58
StackExchange.Ubuntu    2020-05-10 14:51:24
StackExchange.Stats.Meta    2020-05-10 14:51:40
StackExchange.Stats 2020-05-10 14:53:54
StackExchange.Photography.Meta  2020-05-10 14:53:58
StackExchange.Photography   2020-05-10 14:54:33
StackExchange.WebApps   2020-05-10 14:55:06
ServerFault.Meta    2020-05-10 14:55:14
SuperUser.Meta  2020-05-10 14:55:25
StackExchange.Meta  2020-05-10 14:57:16
ServerFault 2020-05-10 15:00:49
SuperUser   2020-05-10 15:07:50
StackOverflow   2020-05-10 19:43:31
...
```

Comment: So it wasn't really stuck, it just started later than usual?