# Why are certain flags not available from time to time?

Tags: support, flags

From time to time, some flags are not available to me. I would, for example, like to flag [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63395457/accidently-ran-sudo-chmod-r-755-command) as off-topic, but the flag is not available for me. (It wasn't before the post was closed, as well.)

The last time this happened, I flagged the post as "in need of moderator intervention" which was not correct, either.

Why are certain flags sometimes not available? Is this some kind of bug, or is there a system that decides which flags I can use on which posts?

Comment: The question you wanted to flag is already closed, so you don't need to flag it to be closed again, hence the close options are not shown. The other flags that are still shown are more for deletion.

Comment: As I stated in my post, the flag was not available before the post was closed, as well.

Comment: Flag dialogs [have changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346638/369802) a little a while back: the off-topic closure ones are now under 'needs improvement - a community specific reason'. Is that option missing as well for you? There's also some rules out there for when the 'very low quality' flag is [shown or not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110754/369802).

Comment: I guess the question was open when you went to the page but closed before you clicked the flag button? The page does not show the closed message until the page is refreshed. If you see this again try refreshing the page to see if the question was closed as you were viewing it.

Comment: Sorry guys, was a "pebcac" problem. @Tinkeringbell hit the nail on the head. I noticed the `very low quality` flag missing and looked for the `off-topic` flag in the wrong place.